# Call of Duty Black Ops - Direct3DDevice9::Present Failed: Ran out of memory

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, technical-issues

Many times my game just crashes giving error "Direct3DDevice9::Present Failed: Ran out of memory (-2147024882)". I can not even complete the second mission of campaign (Vorkuta).

My system is
Operating System: Windows XP SP2
RAM: 1GB DDR2
Processor: 2.0 Dual Core
Graphics Card: 9800GT 1GB
DirectX 9.0 June 2010

Answer (score 4):

1 Gigabyte of RAM is not enough for current games, you need at least 2 Gigabytes, 4 Gigabytes would be better.

You can increase the amount of virtual memory, that might prevent this error, but the performance will be terrible if you're running out of RAM.

The minimum requirements of Call of Duty: Black Ops are

- OS: Windows XP, Vista, 7
- CPU: Core 2 Duo E6600 or AMD Phenom X3 8750 or better
- RAM: 2GB
- HDD: 12GB of free space
- VIDEO: Shader 3.0 or better; 256MB NVIDIA GeForce 8600GT DirectX 9.0c or better
- SOUND: DirectX 9.0c-compatible
- DirectX: 9.0c

The RAM requirements are not met by your computer.

Comment: Going to 4GB won't help that much with a 32 bit OS.

Comment: With a 1GB GPU you are right, that would leave less than 3GB of useful RAM.

Comment: But warfare 2 is running perfect on above configuration

Comment: @LifeH20 Not all games are created equal, but many modern games require 2GB of RAM, and COD:Black Ops is one of them.

Comment: You are wrong Fabian. I have played black ops with same config on windows 7. It surely ran with low FPS but there was no error at all.

Comment: @LifeH20 Minimum requirements are not a hard rule, just a guideline. How much RAM is finally required depends on the OS, the running applications the game settings and more. If you increase your pagefile you pagefile you probably won't see the error, but the performance will most likely suffer due to excessive paging if you have not enough RAM.

Comment: I already increased it to 3GB, going to try even more.

Comment: @ChrisF: 4 GB is max for 32 bit system, you will lose some but you will have max available which is around 3.4GB

Answer (score 2):

Try the lowest possible graphics config and turn off unnecessary services manually or use game booster or something alike. I suggest you add at least one more gigabyte of RAM as your OS occupies around 300 megabytes, leaving just 700 megabytes for your graphic card (which can make use of up to 1 gigabyte, resulting in underperformance).